# Possible to send a push notification from my app when another specific app (Facebook) is opened?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, mobile, push-notification

I have an app, and I was wondering if it's possible for my app to automatically send a push notification whenever someone who has both my app and Facebook installed opens Facebook.  As in, I have an app who's sole purpose is to send a push notification that says "You have opened Facebook!" whenever a user opens the Facebook app.

This is under the assumption that the user had originally granted certain permissions to my app when it was first installed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is but certain that your application will not belong to the same App Group to which the Facebook application belongs.

The only way the 2 applications which do not belong to the same app group can communicate is using URL Schemes.

There is no reason for Facebook to implement your app's URL scheme. Hence, I'm afraid that there is no way your App can communicate with Facebook's app to detect if Facebook was opened; And hence be able to send an push notification.